# Telegram API files uploading

Tags: python, telegram

[Telegram documentation](https://core.telegram.org/api/files) says the following about files ID:

> The file’s binary content is then split into parts. All parts must
>   have the same size (part_size) and the following conditions must be
>   met:
>
> part_size % 1024 = 0 (divisible by 1KB)
>
> 524288 % part_size = 0 (512KB must be evenly divisible by part_size)
>
> The last part does not have to satisfy these conditions, provided its
>   size is less than part_size. Each part should have a sequence number,
>   file_part, with a value ranging from 0 to 2,999.

My code:

```
def check_conditions(file_name):
    b = False
    file_binary_data = open("D:\\" + file_name, "br").read()
    length = len(bytearray(file_binary_data))
    print(file_name + ", size: " + str(length) + " bytes")
    for i in range(1, 3000):
        part = length // i
        if part % 1024 == 0 and 524288 % part == 0:
            print("i: " + str(i) + " | part size: " + str(part))
            b = True
    if not b:
        print("No mathces")
    print()

check_conditions("The White Stripes - Truth Doesn't Make A Noise.mp3")
check_conditions("Depeche Mode - Precious.mp3")
check_conditions("Placebo - Meds.mp3")
```

Output:

```
The White Stripes - Truth Doesn't Make A Noise.mp3, size: 7782220 bytes
No mathces

Depeche Mode - Precious.mp3, size: 10298248 bytes
i: 1257 | part size: 8192
i: 2514 | part size: 4096

Placebo - Meds.mp3, size: 11808625 bytes
No mathces
```

Where is mistake? Or if all's ok, what to do with files that don't meet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting it wrong.

You are simply to divide your file into pieces of equal sizes.

> "The White Stripes - Truth Doesn't Make A Noise.mp3" , size: 7782220
>   bytes

Say you are using the MAX piece size of 512k (ie. 524288), then you simply have:

7782220 / 524288 = 14 rem 442188

Hence you have 14 pieces of 512k bytes and the last piece of 442188 bytes.

Apply same logic to the other files.